# Android 2.1 - Rooted Revue GoogleTV - Flash Plugin Missing in Webview

Tags: flash, android-webview, google-tv, android-2.1-eclair

I am developing and testing a Android 2.1 app on my rooted revue. It needs to render Flash web videos. The app works fine if the flash web videos are launched through an external chrome browser (already installed on the rooted revue). But, I need to do some cookie manipulation. So, I need an internal Webview to launch those videos. I am getting 'Flash Pluggin Missing' error while trying to launch Flash videos through Webview. I tried installing few Flash apk plugins (available on internet for Android 2.1) to make it work. But, all of those Flash Apk failed to install. It says 'INSTALL_FAIL_OLDER_SDK" . Please help me to resolve this issue. I have been struggling for few weeks on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have ran into this problem before and after doing some research, i found that google tv uses two different browser rendering engines. The Chrome browser present in google tv 2.0 uses its own rendering engine based on chrome for linux. It has got its own flash player that just runs on chrome. But in other hand, webview's use webkit rendering engine which is the rendering engine that can be found on normal android phones. The rendering engine cannot access or use the other flash player that is specifically used in Chrome. So the only way to make people use flash content from your webview is to make them install flash player that is found on android market (not on google tv's android market). But the problem is that Google TV"s use x86 instead of ARM architecture in their processor, and flash for android is compiled just for ARM. So unless adobe compiles the flash for android app for x86 processors, or google enables people to embed chrome in their apps instead of webkit webview, its not possible. So the best thing you could do now is create a web tv app instead of a native app. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This explains the whole drama. I was trying to move the wall. Now, I will adopt your suggested strategy or something else.